# Trying to run a chess.pl engine in Sicstus prolog

Tags: prolog, chess, unicode-escapes

I'm [trying to run a chess.pl engine in SICStus prolog](https://github.com/Zebreus/prolog-chess) but I'm getting this error:
Which command should I execute to run that page code ?
I've tried several options none of which works.

(Perhaps `compile chess.pl` in the last but one line in the snippet should be replaced by some other command)

[image]

**EDIT** However `startGame.` **does** something a bit useful:

[image]

But now, `F2,F3.` gives

```
Instantiation error in argument ` of call/1
goal: call(user:_195)
?-
```

Answer (score 3):

This code contains non-standard escape sequences like `\u265B`. Replace these sequences by a standard escape sequence as they are supported by SICStus, like `\x265B\` which denotes a "black chess queen". Note that two backslashes are needed for each such character one at the beginning and one at the end.

As for `read_string/3`, this indicates that the code you have uses a non-standard data type. A relatively fitting replacement in SICStus would be to use atoms in stead. So there will be some more changes here.

Comment: Right, I have replaced `\u` by `\x`. But could you please do the changes `read_string/3` for me ?